# LCM of two periodic signals,

Tags: periodic-functions

Why is $$\text{lcm}\left(\frac{\pi}{5},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\pi$$
where the $10$ here represents the period of $2\cos(10t+1)-\sin(4t-1)$

where $\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{5}$ is the period of $2\cos(10t+1)$ and $\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2}$ is the period of $-\sin(4t-1)$.

The question is not why the lcm but it's why does the lcm of these two give $\pi$.

Comment: Is your question why the LCM gives the period of the sum or why the LCM of $\pi/5,\pi/2$ is $\pi$?

Comment: I want to mark your answer as correct but MSE is telling me to wait 8 more minutes @ShubhamJohri Thank you for your answer I understood it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $n\pi/5=m\pi/2$ where $n,m\in\Bbb Z_{>0}$. For least multiple we need to minimize $m$. We get $n/m=5/2$ and the minimum $m$ that gives $n$ integral is $m=2$.

Answer (score 1):

$$LCM(\frac{a}{b},\frac{c}{d},\frac{e}{f})=\frac{LCM(a,c,e)}{HCF{(b,d,f)}}.$$